# undefined method `gsub' for 121.462488:Float

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ajax call for fetching map data from a third party map api provider.

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery.ajax({type: 'GET', dataType: 'script', url: '/ajax/load_bmap'});
});
```

Above ajax code successfully called the following code in `load_bmap.js.erb`.

```
jQuery('#dituContent').attr('data-x', '<%= j @origin_x %>');
jQuery('#dituContent').attr('data-y', '<%= j @origin_y %>');
```

but it throws the following exception in the log file resulting a 500 internal server error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for 121.462488:Float):
1: jQuery('#dituContent').attr('data-x', '<%= j @origin_x %>');
2: jQuery('#dituContent').attr('data-y', '<%= j @origin_y %>');
```

121.462488 is indeed the x coordinate I am expecting to substitute `data-x` with.

Any help? Many thanks in advance.

### Edit:

Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `@origin_x` and `@origin_y` are not string, then you don't need to (and can't) escape them. Just remove the `j` helper.

```
jQuery('#dituContent').attr('data-x', '<%= @origin_x %>');
jQuery('#dituContent').attr('data-y', '<%= @origin_y %>');
```